# What should I do/visit in Qatar for 8 hours?

Tags: sightseeing, layovers, qatar

I was planning to visit Oslo, Norway with Qatar Airways with a cheap priced ticket.

But it's necessary to wait about 8hours for the transfer at Qatar International Airport. What should I do/visit in Qatar within 8hr?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, make sure you are allowed to leave the airport with your passport/visa.

Visa on arrival is available for many countries, but costs US$28 for 30 days.  But that's only certain countries, other ones are more complicated.

[Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Qatar) is limited, but suggests the following sites:

- The Museum of Islamic Art, Doha
- Souq Waqif : the traditional old marketplace of Qatar. Has many good restaurants, especially at night time. Also sells many national products - bargaining is recommended.
- The Pearl : a man-made island connected to Doha by a bridge. You can find a big variety of restaurants and shops, mainly in the high range.
- Villaggio Mall: a spectacular Venetian style shopping mall with a canal and gondolas as well. A huge variety of shops from casual to luxury.
- Mathaf : The arab museum of modern art
- Katara : Cultural village which is home to many international and Arab restaurants, a beautiful beach, and holds many cultural events. Definitely a place to see.
- Aqua park : Aquatic Funfair.

Personally I'd see maybe one thing, do it properly, and then go hunt out strange foods and experiences.  Middle Eastern cuisine is everywhere, and in many forms — kebabs, breads, hummus, the list goes on.

> Don't be afraid to venture into the Souqs looking for a meal; it will
>   be a unique experience in an authentic setting, and although some of
>   the places you see may look rundown, that's just the area in general,
>   and the food will be probably be quite good. Be advised that many of
>   the restaurants in the Souqs (as well as the shops) shut down during
>   the afternoon hours. If you are in a funny kind of mood, you can try a
>   McArabia—McDonald's Middle Eastern sandwich available only in the
>   region.
>   -- [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Qatar)

Another thing that I did in Dubai, and apparently they offer in Qatar as well is dune-bashing - riding around in big Landcruisers across the desert - it was AMAZING fun! However, after my suggestion of it to a relative went bad - don't do it if you get at all carsick ;)